# Hbase reading multiple keys from multiple readers

Tags: hbase

I am using Hbase 0.94.X,and hadoop 1.0.4 
I want to read all the rows from hbase table but there will be multiple readers and the number of readers can increase in future,Readers have no idea about the keys existing in DB, i want to make sure that each reader gets the key only once process it and then asks for the next key

Like
k1 to kn keys in my hbase table
Reader1 -->process key k1 after processing gets the key k3 since k2 is being processed by Reader2
Reader2-->process key k2 after processing asks for next key

Any pointers on how to achieve this will be of a great help

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use RowMutations. If a process touches a row then it changes something in this row atomically and other processes skip this row.  But if I were you, I will salt rowkeys such as from 1 to 50. When reader processes starts, reader process1 will read salt1, reader process2 will read salt2 etc. By doing this, load on the cluster will also be balanced in this way.

Comment: I have written a  job that reads the keys and place it on kafka ,now as kafka supports multiple consumer my problem is solved :)